# Getting an error when I run Python and scripts in LibreOffice\program directory from C# using IronPython

Tags: python, c#, ironpython, libreoffice

I want to run the python version and scripts that are in the libreoffice\program directory on Windows from C# in Visual Studio 2022 using the latest version of IronPython. The .py script runs fine at the command line.  When I use the following code it wants to use the default version, 3.9, installed by Visual Studio.  The C# code looks like:

```
        string pythonPath = @"D:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\python.exe";
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PythonHome", pythonPath);


        // Initialize the Python engine with the correct Python environment
        var engine = Python.CreateEngine(new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "PythonHome", pythonPath }
        });

        // Create a new scope for executing the Python script
        var scope = engine.CreateScope();

        // Set any necessary variables in the scope
        scope.SetVariable("param1", fileName);
        scope.SetVariable("param2", outputPath);

        engine.ExecuteFile(scriptFile, scope);
```

After a long pause, it errors out with can't find module "Uno" which is in the libreoffice\program path. In the course of trying so many things, I also see Python39 popping up from the Visual Studio install and LibreOffice is 3.8.

So, how can I make it run my script from Python and the scripts in libreoffice\program directory?

Comment: I don't think it works that way — see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to work with the UNO API from C#, then that can be done — https://api.libreoffice.org/examples/examples.html#CLI_examples.

To run the python distro bundled with LO, don't use Iron Python. Instead, chdir to libreoffice/program and then `& ./python.exe`, or run from within LibreOffice such as via *Tools > Macros > Run Macro*.

See also https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/is-there-an-iron-python-compatible-api-access-library-for-calc/21757.

Comment: The intent was to run python from inside VS and be able to step though the code.  Guessing you're saying that won't happen.  I can call the script without a problem.  It was running in VS that I had hoped would work.